# JavaScript - Does a self-invoking anonymous function protect variables against the global namespace sufficiently?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Would this code be better written using a closure?  Is there a better way to write it, or does the function protect the variables?

```
(function(){

    var http = require('http'),
        port = process.argv[2],
        string = "",
        length = 0; 

    http.get(port, function(res){

        res.on('data', function(data){
            length += data.length;
            string += data;
        });

        res.on('end', function(){
            console.log(length);
            console.log(string)
        });
    });

})();
```

Comment: This doesn't leak anything to the global scope, if that's what you're concerned with?

Comment: This keeps variables within the function, and prevents name-collisions, or variable-jacking. So yes it does.

Comment: Are there advantages to using a closure over an anonymous function?  How would it be written using closures?

Comment: Note: Unlike browser-run JavaScript, modules (files) are already contained within closures by Node.js. This is both how and why it also defines `module.exports` in each for revealing values to other modules.

Comment: This is a closure. The IIFE is defining a closure. You inner function (the callback to `http.get`) has access to variables defined in the outer function.

Comment: FWIW these are called ["Immediately-Invoked Function Expression" (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). Seems a better name since it's not self-invoking. I'm not sure what the alternative is that you're proposing, though, since the inner functions *are* accessing a closure. In any case, variables declared with a `var` are scoped only to the function.

Comment: @Triode: How would you "write that using a closure"? You are already!

Answer (score 3):

This does keep variables within to themselves and out of reach to any external code:

```
(function() {
  var so = '//stackoverflow.com';

  alert(so); will alert '//stackoverflow.com'
})();

alert(so); // Will alert Undefined **See note at bottom
```

[Take a look at his post](http://tech.myemma.com/iifes-javascript-control-variable-scope/) I found with a quick google search

**Note:** As stated in a comment below, this will not alert Undefined, but actually throw a reference error, since `so` would be non existent in the scope outside of the IIFE. [Take a look at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) for more!

Comment: Note: The 2nd `alert()` will raise a `ReferenceError` since `so` doesn't exist in that scope. It'll be `undefined` if there's also a `var so;` (declared but unitialized) outside of the IIFE.